# Set image from code

Tags: c#, xaml, resources

I added image to Resources:

```
Right click on project -> Properties -> Resources.
```

Then set variable in `Class`:

var icon = Resources.BLUEJAYF4

In XAML use it like:

```
<Image Source="{Binding icon }" Width="150" Height="150"></Image>
```

But it doesn't show. How to set `Resource path` from code?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this isn't the best way to do it. But this is how I handle binding images programmatically.

You should have a property of BitmapImage like so:

```
    private BitmapImage photoSelected;

    public BitmapImage PhotoSelected
    {
        get { return photoSelected; }
        set { photoSelected = value; OnPropertyChanged("PhotoSelected"); }
    }
```

Then on the action that you desire you do this:

```
PhotoSelected = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Images/4.png"));
```

Replace /Images/4.png with the path to your image starting at the solution level. For example, this is what my solution tree looks like to reach that point:

[image: Solution Tree]

**Edit: I didnt think about this, but here is also the xaml I use to bind to that property.**

```
<Image x:Name="BitMapImage" Source="{Binding PhotoSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"/>
```